# How can I tell if my Lenovo x240 has a solid state drive or not?

Tags: lenovo-laptop

How can I tell if my Lenovo X240 has a SSD or not? I believe it was manufactured in late 2013 or at the latest January 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Go to device manager in the Control Panel; expand "Disk drives".  If all you see is a Samsung Drive, you have an SDD.  Seagate or Western Digital would mean a HDD.

Answer (score 1):

First: Go to [Lenovo Support, Parts Lookup](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/ibasepartslookup/selectproduct?c=1) Choose your model, enter the serial number, and you will see the manufacturer part numbers for your hardware.

On Windows: Try going to *Device Manager* and then *Drives*. You should see your hard disk listed by model number. Alternatively, press 'F1' during boot to go into the BIOS, where the hard drive model number will be listed.

On Linux, run `parted` (*partition editor*) and look for Model: :

```
root@host:~# parted -l | grep Model 
Model: ATA WDC WD10JPVT-22A (scsi)
```

Given the hard drive model, you can find the exact drive in use.

You cannot however just go by the size to determine drive type, as evidenced by the [X240 Lenovo Support](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x240/documents/PD100260?tabName=ProductParts#stor), the solid models of 128, 180, 256 and 500GB overlap with spinning HDs of the same sizes.

x240 HDD sizes:

```
320 GB, 5400rpm, 7mm high, 2.5" wide, SATA 6.0Gb/s
500 GB, 5400rpm, 7mm high, 2.5" wide, SATA 6.0Gb/s
1 TB, 5400rpm, 9.5mm high, 2.5" wide, SATA 6.0Gb/s
320 GB, 7200rpm, 7mm high, 2.5" wide, SATA 6.0Gb/s
500 GB, 7200rpm, 7mm high, 2.5" wide, SATA 6.0Gb/s
128GB, 7mm high, 2.5" wide, SATA 6.0Gb/s
180GB, 7mm high, 2.5" wide, SATA 6.0Gb/s
256GB, 7mm high, 2.5" wide, SATA 6.0Gb/s
500GB, 7mm high, 2.5" wide, SATA 6.0Gb/s
```

x240 SDDs of the following sizes:

```
128GB, 7mm high, 2.5" wide, SATA 6.0Gb/s
180GB, 7mm high, 2.5" wide, SATA 6.0Gb/s
256GB, 7mm high, 2.5" wide, SATA 6.0Gb/s
500GB, 7mm high, 2.5" wide, SATA 6.0Gb/s
```

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo offered 3 SSDs in this model. 128, 180 and 256 Gig.  The non-SSds came in 500 gig and 1 TB.

Comment: This is incorrect according to http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x240/documents/PD100260?tabName=ProductParts#stor

Comment: Accorrding to http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/x-series/x240/ hit customize on the X240 that OFFERS SSD you'll see three sizes offered 120, 180 and 256.